# Write to just one XML attribute without affecting the rest

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following but its not working for me:

```
  static void SaveVersion(string configFile, string Version) 
  {
            XmlDocument config = new XmlDocument();
            config.Load(configFile);

            XmlNode appSettings = config.SelectSingleNode("configuration/appSettings");
            XmlNodeList appKids = appSettings.ChildNodes;

            foreach (XmlNode setting in appKids) 
            {

                if (setting.Attributes["key"].Value == "AgentVersion")
                    setting.Attributes["value"].Value = Version;
            }

            config.Save(configFile);
  }
```

The config file i'm loading up on `config.Load(configFile)` is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="AgentVersion" value="2.0.5" />
    <add key="ServerHostName" value="" />
    <add key="ServerIpAddress" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <add key="ServerPort" value="9001" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Am I missing something? I figured it would edit just that particular attribute `AgentVersion` but its not really doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of the [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class? You can use it to manipulate your `app.config` file without doing anything manually. I don't think you should reinvent the wheel unless you have a good reason to:

```
static void SaveVersion(string configFile, string version) 
{
    var myConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configFile);
    myConfig.AppSettings.Settings["AgentVersion"].Value = version;
    myConfig.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
static void SaveVersion(string configFile, string Version) 
{
    var config = new XmlDocument();
    config.Load(configFile);

    var agentVersionElement = config.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("configuration/appSettings/add[@key = 'AgentVersion']") as XmlElement;
    if (agentVersionElement != null)
        agentVersionElement.SetAttribute("value", version);

    config.Save(configFile);
}
```

Note that I'm doing the `SelectSingleNode` from the `DocumentElement`, not from the `XmlDocument` itself.